# Print arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist

Actually here is an arrayList and i want it to print. But everytime i'm getting error. someone please help me out.`class Product`

```
List<Product> pd = new ArrayList<Product>();
pd.add( new Product("Trouser",40, 499,"Cotton", "Black"));
pd.add( new Product("Shirt",32, 999, "Cotton","White"));
pd.add( new Product("T-Shirt",32, 599 ,"Cotton","Blue"));
pd.add( new Product("Blazer",32, 1299 ,"Cotton","Brown"));
```

So this is the arrayList .. i need to print it .
I tried this way-

```
public static void main(String [] ar)
{
Product pd = new product();
for(Object o : pd)
    {
    Product pd = (Product)o;
    System.out.println(pd);
    }
```

But its not working. Someone please help.
Note: Main method is also a part of class Product.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You probably didn't override `toString` in your `Product` class. And it doesn't help that you declare the `pd`  variable multiple times.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Any exception?

Comment: Can't i print string and integer together?

Comment: What do you mean by `Can't i print string and integer together`?

Comment: `System.out.println(pd.getString() + "" + pd.getInteger());`

Comment: I'm getting errors like **Identtifier expected** **illegal start**

Comment: Can you share complete code for product class?

Comment: `String name;
 int size;
 int price;
 String type;
 String colour;`

Comment: The product class contains these only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be clear about the product list and the individual product.  Here I have renamed the list to be productList for clarity

```
    static List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

When looking through the list, no casting is required

```
        for(Product pd : productList) {
            System.out.println(pd);
        }
    }
```

You need to override the `toString` method to get the output you require

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return(type + " " + n1 + " " + n2 + " " + material + " " + color);
    }
}
```

Putting it all together -

```
public class Product {
    static List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    String type;
    String material;
    String color;
    int n1;
    int n2;

    static void init() {
        productList.add( new Product("Trouser",40, 499,"Cotton", "Black"));
        productList.add( new Product("Shirt",32, 999, "Cotton","White"));
        productList.add( new Product("T-Shirt",32, 599 ,"Cotton","Blue"));
        productList.add( new Product("Blazer",32, 1299 ,"Cotton","Brown"));
    }

    Product (String type, int n1, int n2, String material, String color) {
        this.type = type;
        this.n1 = n1;
        this.n2 = n2;
        this.material = material;
        this.color = color;
    }
    public static void main(String [] ar)
    {
        init();
        for(Product pd : productList) {
            System.out.println(pd);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return(type + " " + n1 + " " + n2 + " " + material + " " + color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working. :) Btw if i need to use individual attributes like product name or size... can i access it just by pd.name or pd.n1 ??

Comment: @Darpanjbora Why don't you try it first?

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar : Yeah sure. :)

Comment: Yeah. It is possible to access in that way. :)

Comment: You need to learn about access control.  If you declare the instance variables as public, they can be accessed anywhere as `pd.color`.  More usual is to have getters and setters which are methods which mediate access to an object's internals.  Variables may also have private, protected or default access which are described in numerous Java tutorials.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions :) @NeilMasson

Answer (score 1):

You should either use `getters/setters` to access individual member variables(String and int) or directly call member variables(if declared as public) from the Product instance like

```
Product pd;
pd.getType();pd.getCount();
```

or

```
pd.type;pd.count;//only if member variables are public
```

If you want just to print all the product member variables; override the toString() method.

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return(type+" "+count+" "+price+" "+material+" "+color);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind that the `pd` you are declared here: `Product pd = new product();` is different from the `pd` you are declaring here:

```
List<Product> pd = new ArrayList<Product>();
pd.add( new Product("Trouser",40, 499,"Cotton", "Black"));
pd.add( new Product("Shirt",32, 999, "Cotton","White"));
pd.add( new Product("T-Shirt",32, 599 ,"Cotton","Blue"));
pd.add( new Product("Blazer",32, 1299 ,"Cotton","Brown"));
```

One is an instance of a list of `Product` objects (the latter) whilst the former is an instance of the `Product` class itself.

Thus, attempting to do this: `for(Object o : pd)` will result in an error, unless `Product` implements the `Iterable` interface.

To fix this problem, you would need to do something like so:

```
List<Product> pd = new ArrayList<Product>();
pd.add( new Product("Trouser",40, 499,"Cotton", "Black"));
pd.add( new Product("Shirt",32, 999, "Cotton","White"));
pd.add( new Product("T-Shirt",32, 599 ,"Cotton","Blue"));
pd.add( new Product("Blazer",32, 1299 ,"Cotton","Brown"));

for(Product p : pd) {
    System.out.println(...);
}
```

Comment: ok . i have changed the object name. But still getting an error.

Comment: @Darpanjbora: Please update your code. Note that just changing the name will not do much difference since the problem is the *type* of the object upon which you are iterating.

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating over list correctly plus there are too many variables named `pd`.

Assuming `pd` is list that contains all product object,

```
for(Product p : pd)
{
  System.out.println(p);
}
```

For this to correctly work,you also need to override [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method in Product class.

Comment: ok i have changed the object name. But what's wrong with the list?

Comment: You need to have that list in main method.I guess you are adding elements in list in Product class which you should do in main and then iterate i have done in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate list you can use either Iterator or enhanced for loop(for each).
 so you can use any one based on your requirment
here i used enhanced for loop

```
List<Product> pd = new ArrayList<Product>();
pd.add( new Product("Trouser",40, 499,"Cotton", "Black"));
pd.add( new Product("Shirt",32, 999, "Cotton","White"));
pd.add( new Product("T-Shirt",32, 599 ,"Cotton","Blue"));
pd.add( new Product("Blazer",32, 1299 ,"Cotton","Brown"));

for the above list you can use the below one

for(Product pro : pd)
{
// here you can get value one by one
System.out.println(pro.toString()); // it will print all the values of list
}
```